# Spark : How to make calls to database using foreachPartition

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have spark streaming job ..writing data to AmazonDynamoDB  using **foreachRDD** but it is very slow with our consumption rate at 10,000/sec and writing 10,000 takes 35min ...this is the code piece ..

```
tempRequestsWithState is Dstream

    tempRequestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>

        if ((rdd != null) && (rdd.count() > 0) && (!rdd.isEmpty()) ) {

          rdd.foreachPartition {

            case (topicsTableName, hashKeyTemp, attributeValueUpdate) => {

              val client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient()
              val request = new UpdateItemRequest(topicsTableName, hashKeyTemp, attributeValueUpdate)
              try client.updateItem(request)


            catch {

                case se: Exception => println("Error executing updateItem!\nTable ", se)

            }

            }

            case null =>


          }
        }
      }
```

From research learnt that using **foreachpartition** and creating a connection per partition will help ..but not sure how to go about writing code for it ..will greatly appreciate if someone can help with this ...Also any other suggestion to speed up writing is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Each partition is handled by an executor(a jvm process). So inside that you can write code to initialize db connection and write to database. IN the code given, the line for first case() is where you write that code. So as you get more partitions, if you have multiple executors writing to db, this will be done in parallel.

```
rdd.foreachPartition {
    //initialize database cnx
    //write to db
    //close connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a single partition to write in a db and singleton to initialize cnx, to decrease the numbers of db connection, in foreachPartition function use write with
batch to increase the numbers of the inserted lines.

```
rdd.repartition(1).foreachPartition {
    //get singleton instance cnx
    //write with batche to db
    //close connection
}
```